# How to user multiple / nested if else in ajax / javascript function.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I have a little code. This code is not working with multiple if else. any one can lep me.?

I am getting data from CI controller to ajax and running a function with this ajax.I post a function only here, I want to check multiple array data so here, I am doing this with below code. Its work fine with one if else. but not working with nested or multiple if else.

```
<script>
  function createDiv(data) {
  var dynamicHTML = '';
  var innerContent = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.res2.length; i++) {
    innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">' +

    if(data.res2[i].paid_type == 1){
        if(data.res3.Status == "success"){ +            
          '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
          '</span>' : '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +       
          '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
          '</span>'+
      } else { + '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +        
      '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
      '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Buy</button>' +
      '</span>'+
      }       
     }

  dynamicHTML += '<div id="' + data.res2.Paper_Type + '" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">' + innerContent + '</div>';
  $('div#tabs_data').append(dynamicHTML);
}
</script>
```

When I try to use if else statement it show me error like

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if'

Comment: I cannot see any `if` syntax in the above code. There is only conditional operator.

Comment: Please post the code that is not working

Comment: it's because error comes with if else statement. I say it in below of my question.

Comment: @moje_mast_ram then show us that code. Not your working code

Comment: @Mendax I edit with code check that..

Comment: That wont work .. `If` block will not return anything. Try making it a function and then call.

Comment: Do you have any example.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to concatenate strings. You cannot insert control flow statements such as `if` in the middle of that.

End the first string with a semicolon, then inside the other `if`s, do `innerContent +=` followed by the string to concatenate it with.

Like this:

```
<script>
  function createDiv(data) {
    var dynamicHTML = '';
    var innerContent = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.res2.length; i++) {
      innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">';

      if (data.res2[i].paid_type == 1) {
        if (data.res3.Status == 'success') {
          innerContent += '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
            '</span>' + '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' +
            data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
            '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
            '</span>';
        } else {
          innerContent += '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
            '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Buy</button>' +
            '</span>';
        }
      }

      dynamicHTML += '<div id="' + data.res2.Paper_Type + '" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">' + innerContent + '</div>';
      $('div#tabs_data').append(dynamicHTML);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: +1, beat me to this. Also, line 12 there is a colon, not sure what that's about. In here: '</span>' : '<label style="p.....

Comment: Yeah, just put it into a proper editor to format and noticed :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var innerContent = '';
innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">';

if (data.res2[i].paid_type == 1) {
  if (data.res3.Status == "success") {
    innerContent += '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
      '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
      '</span>'
  }else {
    innerContent += '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
      '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
      '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
      '</span>'
  }
} else {
  innerContent += '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
    '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
    '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Buy</button>' +'</span>' +
}
```

or you can make it a function which will return the string.

```
var innerContent = '';
innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">' + getString(data);
```

Our `getString` fucntion will check the condition and return the result.

```
function getString(data){
    var processedStr = ''
    if (data.res2[i].paid_type == 1) {
      if (data.res3.Status == "success") {
        processedStr += '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
          '</span>'
      }else {
        processedStr += '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
          '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
          '</span>'
      }
    } else {
      processedStr += '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
        '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Buy</button>' +'</span>' +
    }

 return processedStr;
}
```